# In vb.net, how do I get files from a directory based on a comma separated string?

Tags: vb.net

I need to create an `array()` from files in a folder. Here's an example of how I would get all files within a folder.

```
Dim filesList = New DirectoryInfo("MyPath").GetFiles("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(Function(f) Not f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)).[Select](Function(f) New AClassNameHere(f)).ToArray()
```

I want to do the exact same thing, but only get files that exist in a comma separated string.

```
Dim myFiles as String = "filename1.jpg,filename2.jpg,filename3.jpg"
```

Where you see the `AClassNameHere` is a class I need to send each file to, and it would also be great if I knew how to send additional data about each file, like its type, size, etc.

Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could narrow the query results by adding an additional `.Where()` filter

```
Dim myFiles as String = "filename1.jpg,filename2.jpg,filename3.jpg"
Dim filesList = New DirectoryInfo("MyPath")
                .GetFiles("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                .Where(Function(f) Not f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
                .Where(Function(f) myFiles.Contains(f.Name))
                .[Select](Function(f) New AClassNameHere(f)).ToArray()
```

A better option would be to ensure that all filenames follow a pattern.

```
New DirectoryInfo("MyPath").GetFiles("filename*.jpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

Comment: That is simply awesome. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. The file control I'm building allows different file types, so I'm stuck with having to search for the full name of the file based on the file types the user chooses in the settings. Appreciate it very much.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that `GetFiles("*")` will get all files, discarding the `FileInfo` objects that are not needed only after they have been created. This slows your app when the target directory has tons of files.

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
    Dim Files() As String
    Files= filesList.Split(",")

    For each File In Files
    Msgbox(File)
    Next
```

Comment: That isn't quite what I had in mind but I appreciated it. Instead of looping through an array I was hoping to use that comma separated string as the search expression.